# Tiles library requires a struts class even though webapp is based on spring

Tags: java, spring, tiles, struts-1

I have an old webapp that depends on struts 1.2.9 and spring 2.0.6. It also uses tiles 1.1

I removed all the struts actions and replaced them with spring controllerr. I thought it was safe to remove the struts jar, but unfortunately my tiles still depends on it somehow. When I try to deploy the webapp, I get an error in my Tilesconfigurer bean:

> Could not instantiate bean TilesConfigurer because the class
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles.TilesConfigurer depends on
>   the class org.apache.struts.tiles.xmlDefinition.I18nFactorySet which
>   could not be found

I tried to look for the equivalent of that class in spring, but because both the spring and the tiles are very old, I'm having troubles finding any decent downloadable jars.

Is there any way to remove this "dependency" and make tiles work using only spring classes?

Comment: No. You need struts, because back then tiles was part of struts.

Comment: What @M.Deinum said, or you could upgrade to Tiles 2 and use it without struts.